# Structuring objects for proper MVVM in Knockout

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm working with knockout and am trying to stay true the MVVM structure and trying to make the objects have that dependency on each other.

Model, ViewModel, Service definitions:

```
var App = window.App || {};

(function(ns, $, ko) {
    ns.Models = {};
    ns.ViewModels = {};
    ns.Services = ns.Services || {};

    //Service def
    ns.Services.SearchService = function() {
        this.SearchByName = function(name, callback) {
            $.get("/api/SearchByName/" + name, function(d){
                callback(d);
            });
        };
    };

    //Model Def
    ns.Models.SearchResultModel = function(json) {
        var self = this;

        ko.mapping.fromJS(json, {}, self);
    };

    //ViewModel def
    ns.ViewModels.SearchResultsViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;

        self.dataService = new ns.Services.SearchService();
        self.SearchResults = ko.observableArray();

        self.GetSearchResultsByName = function(name){
            self.dataService.SearchByName(name, function(d) {
                $.each(d, function(i, e) { self.SearchResults.push(new ns.Models.SearchResultModel(e)); });
            });
        };
    };
}(App, jQuery, ko));
```

And I can currently use it like so:

```
var vm = new App.ViewModels.SearchResultsViewModel();

vm.GetSearchResultsByName("Doe");

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("search-results-form"));
```

This is just my starting point and it seems like the `ko.applyBindings(...)` should be in the `ViewModel` somewhere.

With all that, am I going the right direction for this or am I completely off with it?

Answer (score 2):

This looks good me, just as it looked good for the SO reviewers.

Some thoughts;

- Consider `'use strict';`
- Consider naming your anonymous functions
- It is not clear how `SearchResultModel` deals with failed calls
- `var self = this;` is only needed for closures, you don't need it in `ns.Models.SearchResultModel`

All in all, pretty solid.